# Stop py.exe from opening new console window

Tags: python, launcher

I'm user of both Pythons 2 & 3.
I need to launch my scripts from PowerShell, currently `.\script.py` opens a new console window. I know it's result of using `py.exe` which is Windows' wrapper capable of recognizing *shebangs*. Good, I need that!

However, is there a way to stop such behavior of `py.exe` when I run script directly from command line? After script ends, the history is gone, and then I have a trouble if another script calls for Python script.

I googled for solution without luck.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Why do you need to run the scripts from Powershell? Why run the script with `./script.py` and not `python script.py`? Why do you need shebangs?

Comment: You need re-associate .py files with pythonw.exe which do not start cmd. You can find more info in documentation https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm unix kind of guy, on any Linux I can simply use `./script.py`. Moreover `python` may call wrong python and I don't want to remember in which Python the script is written.

@RomanPatutin Poor advice, as `pythonw` swallows all output and send it to Windows equivalent of `/dev/null`...

Comment: On my Windows sytem I do it by creating a shortcut that executes `C:\Python\pythonw.exe "C:\path_to\myscript.py"`. This will run the Python 2.x version I have installed in that directory. If I wanted to run it with Python 3.x, I would change the first part to `C:\Python3\pythonw.exe'` which is where I have that version installed. Basically I'm **not** using `py.exe` to launch the script.

Comment: BTW, what I'm doing is similar to what's suggested in the documentation — see the second to last paragraph of section [3.4.1. Python Application](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#python-application).

Comment: Another thought. Try changing the extension of the script to `.pyw` which I think will make `py.exe` do the right thing based on the shebang in the script file.

Comment: @AlonYeager Why do you correct my British English spelling?

Comment: @Manveru Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you need to rename your script file:
from: `scriptfile_name.py`
to: `scriptfile_name.pyw`